# Give an approximation for $f(-1)$ with an error margin of less than $0.01$

Tags: calculus

$f$ is defined by the power series: $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{3^n (n+2)}$ 
I need to find an approximation for $f(-1)$ such that the error margin will be less than $0.01$.

I know I need to use the Taylor remainder and the Laggrange theorem, but I'm not exactly sure how. All the other times I had a function (not a series) and I knew how to calculate. Now I have a series and I don't really understand what to do

Comment: If you are looking for an exact answer, I post it below. If you are interested more in numerical analysis result, the approach is different. You can separate the series in positive and negative terms, and approximate each to the desired accuracy, by bounding the reminder (for which you can employ the sum of a geometric series perhaps). The bound on the remainder will tell you at which value of $n$ you can stop in order to have 2 accurate digits. Seems that the first two terms will give an error about $5\times 10^{-3}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just for your curiosity.*

As @gammatester answered, you are looking fo $n$ such that $$\frac 1{3^n(n+2)}\lt \frac 1{100}$$ which can rewrite $$3^n(n+2)\gt 100$$ Just by inspection, $n=3$ is the samllest value for which the inequality holds.

In fact, there is an analytical solution to the equation $$x^n(n+k)=\frac 1 \epsilon$$ It is given by $$n=\frac{W\left(\frac{x^k \log (x)}{\epsilon }\right)}{\log (x)}-k$$ where $W(z)$ is [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). As you will see in the Wikipedia page, since, in a case like your, the argument is quite large, you have a good approximation using $$W(z)=L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(z)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$. Applied to you case $(x=3, k=2,\epsilon=\frac 1 {100})$, this would give, as a real, $$n\approx \frac{5.24544}{\log(3)}-2\approx 2.7746$$

May I suggest you play with this to see how many terms would be required for an error margin of, say, $10^{-6}$ ?

Sooner or later, you will learn that any equation which can write $$A+Bx+C\log(D+Ex)=0$$ has analytical solution in terms of the beautiful Lambert function.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this without Taylor series. Observe that
$$f(-1) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{3^n(n+2)}.$$ This is a convergent [alternating series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series) with $a_n=\frac{1}{3^n(n+2)}$ and you can use the error term
$$\Big|f(-1) -\sum_{n=1}^m (-1)^n a_n\Big| \le a_{m+1}$$
Since $a_3= 1/135 \approx  0.0074\;$ you have 
the approximation $$f(-1) = -\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{36} = -\frac{1}{12}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let us find a closed form for $H(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{(n+2)}$. Note that  $$x^2 H(x) \equiv G(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+2}}{n+2}$$.

We proceed to find $G(x)$ in closed from. Then, your answer is $f(-1)=H(-1/3)=G(-1/3)/(-1/3)^2$.

Note that: $G'(x) =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n+1}$ and $G(0)=0$. Hence, (for $\vert x\vert <= 1$) we just sum up a geometric series: $$\frac{dG}{dx}(x)=\frac{x^2}{1-x} \quad \cal{and} \quad G(0)=0.$$

The solution reads $$G(x)=-(x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\ln\vert1-x\vert).$$

To conclude this, the final answer is $9 G(-1/3) = -8.913865206602750 \times 10^{-2}$ (confirmed numerically also).

Answer (score 0):

$$f(-1)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n (n+2)}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n+1}\,dx = -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2}{3+x}\,dx \tag{1}$$
hence $f(-1)=\frac{5}{2}-9\log\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)$ and it is enough to find a good approximation of $\log\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)$. Since:
$$ \log\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)=\log\left(\frac{1+\frac{1}{7}}{1-\frac{1}{7}}\right)=2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)7^{2n+1}}\tag{2}$$
and the last series converges really fast, we may approximate $\log\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)$ with
$$ 2\sum_{n=0}^{1}\frac{1}{(2n+1)7^n}=\frac{296}{1096} \tag{3}$$
and the approximation error is way less than $\frac{1}{100}$, it is about $3\cdot 10^{-5}$. That leads to:
$$ \boxed{\;f(-1) \approx \color{red}{-\frac{61}{686}}\;} \tag{4}$$
with an approximation error that is about $3\cdot 10^{-3}$.